# show different images depending on property in a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to show different images depending on specific value of property.
This is my way to accomplish this task.

I have the model:

```
public class DetailInfoViewModel
{
    public string Status {get; set;}
    public string StatusImageName {get; set;}
    ... other fields
}
```

In the action:

```
var model = ...// create view model and fill properties    
model.StatusImageName = GetImageFileNameForStatus(model.Status.ToLower());
```

and, the main method:

```
private string GetImageFileNameForStatus(string status)
{
    if (status == "payed" || status == "approved")
        return "payed.png";

    if (status == "printed")
        return "not-pay.png";

    if (status == "closed")
        return "closed.png";

    if (status == "transfer")
        return "transfer.png";

    return string.Empty;
}
```

In the view I have the simple html:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/" + Model.StatusImageName)"/>
</div>
```

But this way is ugly. If I rename image or make misprint then this code will not work properly.
There is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it less error prone, consider making the status an enum

```
enum Status { Payed, Printed, Closed, Approved, Transfer}
```

And use [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) to generate strong links to the resources:

```
private string GetImageFileNameForStatus(Status status)
{
    switch(status){
      case Payed:
      case Approved:
        // This is generated by T4MVC for you
        return Links.Content.Images.payed_png;
      case Printed:
        return Links.Content.Images.not_pay_png;          
      // ... etc.
      default:
        return Links.Content.Images.default_png;
    }
}
```

Instead of a switch statement, you could save the information inside a `Dictionary<Status, string>`, but that's an implementation detail.

You can then use similarly to this:

```
<img src="@Model.StatusImageName" alt="@Model.Status"/>
```

NB: remember to add the alt attribute!

If you rename images or move them, compilation will now break.

This solution should be acceptable for most smaller systems. Read on if you're interested in more complex, "pure OOP" solutions (which could suffer from over-engineering, depending on the use case).

From a pure OOP perspective, this switch - while comparatively simple - isn't the most beautiful solution. You might consider the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) ([.NET implementation](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx)).

```
interface IStatus{
    string InfoImage{get;}
}

class PayedStatus : IStatus {    
    public string InfoImage{get{return Links.Content.Images.payed_png;}}
}

class PrintedStatus : IStatus {    
    public string InfoImage{get{return Links.Content.Images.not_pay_png;}}
}

// etc.
```

And your model:

```
public class DetailInfoViewModel
{
  ... 
  public IStatus Status{get;set;}
}
```

In your view:

```
<img src="@Model.Status.InfoImage" alt="Status"/>
```

This approach is even better if there are things specific to a given status. You can encapsulate everything related to a specific status neatly inside the respective IStatus implementation.

Again, from an object-oriented-design perspective, it feels weird that UI details (which image to display) become part of the model. On the other hand, it's a view model, so why not. If you want to go die-hard OOP and the system complexity and requirements warrant it, you could consider the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) ([.NET implementation](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternVisitor.aspx)):

```
interface IStatusVisitor<T>{
   T VisitPayedStatus<T>(PayedStatus status);
   T PrintedStatus<T>(PrintedStatus status);
   // ...
}

interface IStatus{
    T Accept(IStatusVisitor<T> visitor);
}

class PayedStatus : IStatus {    
    public T Accept(IStatusVisitor<T> visitor){
        return visitor.VisitPayedStatus(this);
    }
}

class PrintedStatus : IStatus {    
    public T Accept(IStatusVisitor<T> visitor){
        return visitor.VisitPrintedStatus(this);
    }
}


class InfoImageVisitor : IStatusVisitor<string>{

  public string VisitPayedStatus(PayedStatus status){
    return Links.Content.Images.payed_png;
  }

  public string VisitPrintedStatus(PrintedStatus status){
    return Links.Content.Images.not_pay_png;
  }

}


<img src="@Model.Accept(new InfoImageVisitor())" alt="Status"/>
```

This way you move everything about the info image out of the state classes to a separate class.

But as I said, this can already be considered a case of over-engineering. It depends on the requirements of your system.

As a general note: it's definitively worth to read up on design patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I think the solution is too heaped up to the task.

Comment: As I said, the state pattern and visitor pattern might be overkill, but consider the enum + T4MVC approach. It'll help you catch errors at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this is the best way, but you can define imageName as status Name, I mean

```
status | statusImage |
----------------------
 payed |   payed.png |
closed |  closed.png |
   ... |         ... |
```

Then

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/" + Model.Status) + ".png""/>
</div>
```